# Access arrays with unknown names in php class

Tags: php, virtuemart

There is class Cart in Virtuemart plugin (php). I need to access product list (get ids) when order is confirmed. But these ids are names of arrays. Here is part of of a class that gives php's print_r built-in function:

```
VirtueMartCart Object
(
    ...
    ...
    [pricesUnformatted] => Array
        (
            [basePrice] => 580
            ...
            [71] => Array
                (
                    [costPrice] => 40.00000
                    ...
                )

            [60] => Array
                (
                    [costPrice] => 90.00000
                    ...
                )

            ...
        )
        ...
)
```

In this example ids are 71 and 60. How can I access such arrays? Names and quantity of Arrays ("71", "60") will be different each order.

Comment: well if the id's you want are always integers and everything other key is a string then loop, cast key to `(int)`, check if it `==` key, then you know its a integer

Comment: I didn't understand the question completely, but does `foreach` (or something like `array_keys` function) solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Iam Assuming that you are trying to acccess the cart details inside the plugin `(something like ,shipping or payment etc)`.

So right now which values is you printed is just need to parse like below.

```
 foreach($cart->products as $keyProducts=>$keyItems){
        echo $ProductsId = $keyItems->virtuemart_product_id;
    }
```

You can also access any details of the products that available in cart object by using this method.

Hope its helps..